# Currency changer from a drop down

Tags: excel, vba

I have a drop down list in `$C$4` where you can select your desired currency for the sheet (£, €, $) . I am looking for a piece of code that will identify that cells within the sheet are all one of the above and change them to your selected currency.

For example, the cells currently all contain dollar signs (in accountancy formatting) and you choose € from the dropdown, now all cells that are dollars become euros.

This code below caters for `A1`.but I need a test for all cells in the sheet containing accountancy format. (some number cells don't)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$B$1" Then
    Select Case Target.Value
        Case Is = "US Dollars"
           Range("A1").NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"

        Case Is = "British Pounds"
            Range("A1").NumberFormat = "[$£-809]#,##0.00"

        Case Else
            Range("A1").NumberFormat = "general"
    End Select
End If
End Sub
```

Your thoughts,thanks

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$B$1" Then

    Select Case Target.Value
        Case Is = "US Dollars"
           Range("A1").NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
        
        Case Is = "British Pounds"
            Range("A1").NumberFormat = "[$£-809]#,##0.00"
            
        Case Else
            Range("A1").NumberFormat = "general"
    
    End Select

End If

End Sub'

Comment: Why dont you just use cell styles? change the master style and then will all update.

Answer (score 0):

I now have two important lines written:

```
Application.Union(["CPC"], ["heading"], ["final4"], ["single"]).Name = "CombinedRange"

 Range("CombinedRange").NumberFormat= _
"_-[$$-1004]* #,##0_ ;_-[$$-1004]* -#,##0 ;_-[$$-1004]* ""-""_ ;_-@_ "

Range("CombinedRange").NumberFormat= _
"_-[$$-1004]* #,##0_ ;_-[$$-1004]* -#,##0 ;_-[$$-1004]* ""-""_ ;_-@_ "

Range("CombinedRange").NumberFormat= _
"_-[$€-2] * #,##0_-;-[$€-2] * #,##0_-;_-[$€-2] * ""-""_-;_-@_-"
```

I need a piece of code that says if C4="USD":  Range("CombinedRange").NumberFormat=  $

else if... c4="Euro" ; Range("CombinedRange").NumberFormat=  €